# Конфликт ip-адресов

Tags: winsock, c++

Программа-сервер для игры. Через winsock получает внешние ip-адреса тех, кто подключается ко мне, но иногда как будто в случайном порядке некоторые получают мой ip-адрес. С чем это может быть связано? Виноват код программы или способ подключения к интернету или что-то ещё?

**Обновление**

Вообщем, они ко мне подключаются, но я должен идентифицировать их в программе по их ip, но не могу этого сделать, так как вместо их ip у них установлен мой. То есть как будто они подключились ко мне с моего же ip. Такое происходит не всегда, а как-то случайно и для 1-2 из 10 примерно.

Comment: К тебе подключаются, зная твой IP-адрес. О чём вопрос?

Comment: @xinakapu, Вы уверены, что

    int getpeername(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);

возвращает в `*addr` Ваш IP?

Если так, то посмотрите утилитой `lsof`, что это за процесс.

Comment: @avp - если человек пишет о winsock, то вряд ли у него будет lsof.

@xinakapu - а может у Вас антивирус/торрент/фаервол/вирусня или что то подобное? Вот оно и подключается. Просто понаблюдайте, что там передается, возможно и получите ответ. Wireshark - хороший инструмент для этого.